Rails 8: Why does my link point to #show not #destroy?
I am adding a simple log out link to my menu bar. It should fire SessionsController#destroy:
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
#...

  def destroy
    terminate_session
    redirect_to new_session_path
  end
end

Here are my routes:
 new_session GET    /session/new(.:format)   sessions#new
edit_session GET    /session/edit(.:format)  sessions#edit
     session GET    /session(.:format)       sessions#show
             PATCH  /session(.:format)       sessions#update
             PUT    /session(.:format)       sessions#update
             DELETE /session(.:format)       sessions#destroy
             POST   /session(.:format)       sessions#create

I am creating my link like so: <%= link_to 'Delete', session_path, method: :delete %>
However, when I click on it, Rails looks for the #show action.
Unknown action
The action 'show' could not be found for SessionsController

How do I for the #destroy action instead of #show? Is this a limitation of the browser?

With Turbo you need to use data: { turbo_method: :delete } as it the data attributes are all "namespaced". Or better yet use <%= button_to 'Delete', session_path, method: :delete %>  which doesn't rely on JS. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#method

links in html are intended to take the user to a new location when clicked (hence GET method), whereas buttons are intended to execute some action on the server. If you want to control how the link/button appears on the page, you can use css.
